# Page break between columns group in RDCL report

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have on table matrix with columns group. I want that the table length is break on new page if change the group value. Example of my table;

```
  GROUP COLUMN 1       |    GROUP  COLUMN 2
        |mounth1 | month2 | month3  |  mounth4 | month5 | month6   
  TEXT1 |
  ............................................................
  TEXT1 |
  ............................................................
```

Some one can help me?

EDIT:
[image]
I uploaded an image of the report. It's a very simple matrix table. I would like page break after the "Periodo" column its was changed value.
Thank...

Answer (score 0):

In your Design, in the group properties of your Group Column, you can set, in "Page Breaks" option the option "Between each instance of a group"

[image]

Comment: that's weird.. As I can see in your image, you got the column grouped by "Previsto" and "Maturato" (In Periodo).. Are you sure you got more than one result for that group ?