# SSRS Matrix Page Break of Column Groups

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-grouping

I am currently working with SSRS 2012 and have apparently hit a road block.  Is it possible to set a page break on each new instance of of a column group variable.  I have given a basic example below.

[image]

I have selected the page break across group option (picture below).

[image]

I notice that there is a similar post - without working answer - [Another Column Group - Page Break Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11364448/page-break-between-columns-group-in-rdcl-report)

I have done a few hours of research on the web and found that this functionality 'may' not exist?  I know it works for row groups.  If this function does not exist - is it possible force it to do this via code?

Thank you in advance for any help you can offer on this.

Comment: Does it have to be a column group, rather than a row group? As you state, this is pretty straightforward in the latter case.

Comment: I guess I could transpose the entire table (row to columns and columns to rows) - as you suggest.  The format is historical Excel format that I am emulating...This may be the only choice - thank you for the suggestion in the meantime! It would be nice to to actually do keep it as it is though..

Comment: Visually, it shouldn't change much- you can hide the column that displays the name of the row group.